# Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. Severity 16 State 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My select is like this:

```
SELECT @rc0 + CHAR(10) + @rc1 + CHAR(10) + LEFT(@rc2, LEN(@rc2) - 1)
```

I dont know why it is giving me this error.

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. Severity 16 State 5 .
```

@rc2 is like this .

```
SELECT @rc2 = @rc2+'2;'+@OrderNumber+';'+ CASE @IsLimitOrder WHEN 1 THEN isnull([Valore_Colonna],'') ELSE '' END +';'+isnull(@TaxableAmount, '')+''+CHAR(10)
```

and I want to remove the last char(10)

I try this is that right ??

```
SELECT @rc0 + CHAR(10) + @rc1 + CHAR(10) +LEFT(@rc2, LEN(isnull(@rc2,'')) - 1)
```

Comment: "This error" - What error?

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. Severity 16 State 5

Comment: `@rc2` might be null in that case `Len(@rc2)` will be 0. Therefore Left function will trow an error because of negative value . `Left(@rc2,-1)`

Comment: Is @ordernumber int or string type?

Comment: and @rc2 is defined with sufficient storage. hope it is not char(10)

Comment: Try this :- `SELECT @rc0 + CHAR(10) + @rc1 + CHAR(10) + LEFT(@rc2, LEN(coalesce(@rc2,1)) - 1) `

Comment: praveen -- error
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2;6600007205;6600007208;

Comment: the `1` inside the coalesce function should be in quotes. `LEN(coalesce(@rc2,'1'))` as the variable @rc2 is string

Comment: I find that sometimes len @rc2 return 0 in the select

Comment: look I update my question I try something

Answer (score 0):

LEN is either returning a NULL or a 0 . Put in a Null check ON @RC2